# What computer (possibly a PC compatible) rendered a spinning floppy disk on the screen on a boot error?

Tags: floppy-disk, boot, identify-this-computer

I recall seeing an IBM PC compatible or similar system many years ago in a business environment that had a distinctive boot error screen. The system showed a spinning floppy disk on the screen, prompting the user (if I recall correctly) to insert a boot disk, and restarted itself every few minutes or so in this state. The graphic was relatively crude: it was monochrome and drawn in text mode. It's this spinning floppy graphic that caught my eye but sadly, I was never able to take a closer look at the system. I believe the system took 5.25" floppies, and was not recent enough to use 3.5" disks.

Any idea what this system was?

Comment: some old Compaq perhaps? they needed a floppy to go to BIOS setup.

Comment: Did *any* IBM PC compatible ever natively use 8" floppies? I can't think of any, and it would make data exchange with other types of systems quite difficult since with the typical 5.25" bays, you couldn't even fit an 8" drive in the box if you wanted to.

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm pretty sure they were 5.25" floppies. The floppy disk graphic on the screen was animated to make it look like it was spinning (IIRC a square moving in the center of the disk) and looked like a 5.25" disk.

Comment: The NeXT was pretty famous for its nice boot animations and showed, amongst other stuff, the image of a spinning hard disk.

Comment: The Apple Mac had a floppy disk with a question mark superimposed IIRC.

Comment: Excuse my stupidity, but how can a floppy picture on screen be spinning? Especially when considering the rather low resolutions back then. Even less that there's no processing power availabe for animation during floppy search.

Comment: @Raffzahn The Amiga can do full motion animation during floppy access IIRC because the floppy is handled by a separate controller (the CIA). The PC can only change the screen between sectors, but that could still be used to animate a small icon once a second or so. A SCSI floppy controller might offload the CPU enough for better animations than a PC can handle.

Comment: @traal :)) Well, even an original PC could do a lot with a modified BIOS. Then again, the number of manufacturers that did write their own BIOS is incredible small. Isn't it? So, was it an Amiga? Otehrwise I stand.

Comment: It was in text mode – to the best of my knowledge, it was't with any particularly fancy graphics hardware. Could be of AT or XT vintage or a somewhat later PC-type machine, though.

Comment: I wonder: could it have been a custom boot ROM eg for a network boot, showing up if network booting fails?  I'd have thought that between the people who've already looked at this we'd recognize that if it was part of a major manufacturer's BIOS, and as Raffzahn points out the little guys generally didn't have their own BIOS, but used one of the big name compatibles (Phoenix, AMI, etc).  But a network boot ROM is a much simpler thing, so there was probably much more variation between them...

Comment: @Raffzahn PCs have their own separate floppy controller and also support DMA so there's very little CPU involvement necessary when using floppies. They also support disk change notification which can be cheaply polled while animating an icon and waiting for the user to insert a disk. Also a lot manufactures took the Pheonix/AMI/Award BIOS and added their own customizations, just like modern motherboard manufactures.

Comment: Even if we were to accept that animation isn't possible on the PC architecture (disclaimer: I have no idea about the extent to which the DMA controller reduces bus availability on the IBM PC), since the original poster says only that it is an "IBM PC compatible or similar" surely that would just be a clue that it's a 'similar' or else an extended 'compatible'? @bwDraco which country was this in? That might help to limit options.

Comment: @Tommy: United States (more specifically, New York). The system was intended for business (IIRC data entry/secretarial) uses. Chances are good it's an extended compatible, but as far as I recall, the computer in question did not have any special graphics hardware – the animation was entirely in text mode. I might be mistaken as to whether it was an IBM PC compatible or kin, but it *looked* like one. It did have a horizontal form factor.

Comment: @RossRidge I'm well aware about the technical abilities of the PC. Have done hardware for them since the very first 5150. Still, this is not about what can be done if your'a an dedicated hacker with enough time on your hand, but a company selling stuff with the intention to make money 8and be compatible:

Comment: @Raffzahn It's easily within the capabilities of anyone writing or customizing a BIOS.

Comment: @RossRidge Do you realy think and management, who just payed quite some money for a contract to buy a BIOS, is eager to spend more money (BIOS programmers wheren' a dime a dozend even back then) on such a gimmick? Rather unlikely after what I experienced working for this kind of companies. But yeah, maybe i was features like that why noone seams toremember that feature :))

Comment: @Raffzahn Yes, as I already said, a lot of manufacturers customized their BIOSes.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling: I have personally used early MS-DOS running CompuPro & Xerox systems that natively used 8" floppies.  There were a lot of more or less obscure systems like this during the time when manufacturers were migrating from 8-bit (8080/Z-80) to 16-bit (8088/8086).  In fact, 8" floppies were supported standard by MS-DOS until 2.11, as I recall.

Comment: Some models of the IBM PC had an "insert boot floppy" animation. It was monochrome, character-mode, and showed a hand putting the disk into the drive. IIRC it only had a few frames of animation. But there was no spinning. Is there a chance that could be it?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I worked with CompuPro for years. I don't consider an MS-DOS machine to be "IBM Compatible" unless it has compatible video a high degree of hardware compatibility. Few, if any, of the earlier CompuPro systems had that - they were at best MS-DOS (not BIOS and hardware) compatible. Some of the later machines (386) were more compatible using Concurrent DOS to map the video, etc. but still not what I would call "IBM compatible" - though they were very good machines in many other ways. The last batch of machines were true clones - and a big step down from the S100 machines.

Comment: @manassehkatz *"I don't consider an MS-DOS machine to be "IBM Compatible" unless it has compatible video a high degree of hardware compatibility."* This question, however, specifically calls out *IBM PC compatible or similar system*.

Comment: @hobbs: Possibly – do you have a video of it?

Comment: @bwDraco https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgGB_ksVvck isn't the exact one I remember, but it's in the right spirit :)

Comment: @hobbs: Unfortunately, that wasn't what I was looking for. Thanks for trying, though. (The screen contained an error message and a text prompt to insert a disk, in addition to the animation.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling 8" drives would be in their own enclosures.  The cabling would be very close to 5.25" HD drives.

Comment: Might the Research Machines Nimbus 186 have had such an animation? I find no direct evidence, but some screenshots are suggestive ( https://www.thenimbus.co.uk/gallery/RM%20Nimbus%20with%20Phillips%20Monitor.jpg ; https://www.thenimbus.co.uk/gallery/Slimline%20RM%20Nimbus.jpg ).